# How to Stop UI thread until Network Thread Completes?

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I am displaying some data from `JSON` into my `AccordionView`. The problem is that my View thread completes executing before my Network Thread. So I Can't populate the Data which I get from the Array to my AccordionView.

So it shows that `Array index out of range` exception. I also tried using the reloadData Method But it is of no use.

I researched this issue and found about GCD. I can't figure out how to use GCD for this issue.

This is the [AccordionView](http://www.innofied.com/accordion-view-ios/) Library.

```
    import UIKit
    import Alamofire
    import SwiftyJSON


    var CourseIdinController : String!
    var CourseDescriptionC: String!
    var ChapNameC : [String] = []
    var titleLabel : UILabel?

    class CoursePageController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet weak var courseDesc: UITextView!

            var CourseName : String!

            var ChapName : [String] = []

        var LessonName : [String] = []
        var myAccordionView : MKAccordionView?

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.title = CourseName
            self.courseDesc.text = CourseDescriptionC
            self.courseDesc.setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated: true)

            view.bounds.size.height = 450.0
            myAccordionView = MKAccordionView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 111, CGRectGetWidth(view.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(view.bounds)));
            println(ChapNameC.count)
            myAccordionView!.delegate = self;
            myAccordionView!.dataSource = self;
            view.addSubview(myAccordionView!);
            getData()
            getlData()

        }

                func getData(){
                    Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://www.wgve.com/index.php/capp/get_chapter_by_course_id/\(CourseIdinController)")
                        .responseJSON { (_, _, data, _) in
                            let json = JSON(data!)
                            let catCount = json.count
                            for index in 0...catCount-1 {
                                let cname = json[index]["CHAPTER_NAME"].string
                                self.ChapName.append(cname!)
                                println(self.ChapName[index])
                              }
                                self.myAccordionView!.tableView?.reloadData()

                    }}

        func getlData(){
            Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://www.wgve.com/index.php/capp/get_lesson_by_course_id/\(CourseIdinController)")
                .responseJSON { (_, _, data, _) in
                    let json = JSON(data!)
                    let catCount = json.count
                    for index in 0...catCount-1 {
                        let cname = json[index]["LESSON_NAME"].string
                        self.LessonName.append(cname!)

                    }
                      self.myAccordionView!.tableView?.reloadData()
            }}


        func accordionView(accordionView: MKAccordionView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            var cell : UITableViewCell? = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: nil)
            //cell?.imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "lightGrayBarWithBluestripe"))

            // Background view
            var bgView : UIView? = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(accordionView.bounds), 50))
            var bgImageView : UIImageView! = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "lightGrayBarWithBluestripe"))
            bgImageView.frame = (bgView?.bounds)!
            bgImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
            bgView?.addSubview(bgImageView)
            cell?.backgroundView = bgView

            // You can assign cell.selectedBackgroundView also for selected mode

            cell?.textLabel?.text = LessonName[0]
            return cell!
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
            // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
        }



    }

    // MARK: - Implemention of MKAccordionViewDatasource method
    extension CoursePageController : MKAccordionViewDatasource {

        func numberOfSectionsInAccordionView(accordionView: MKAccordionView) -> Int {
                    println(ChapName.count)
        return ChapName.count
        }

        func accordionView(accordionView: MKAccordionView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            println(LessonName.count)
        return LessonName.count
        }
    }

// MARK: - Implemention of MKAccordionViewDatasource method
extension CoursePageController : MKAccordionViewDatasource {

    func numberOfSectionsInAccordionView(accordionView: MKAccordionView) -> Int {
        return ChapName.count
    }

    func accordionView(accordionView: MKAccordionView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return LessonName.count

    }
}

// MARK: - Implemention of MKAccordionViewDelegate method
extension CoursePageController : MKAccordionViewDelegate {

    func accordionView(accordionView: MKAccordionView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }

    func accordionView(accordionView: MKAccordionView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }

    func accordionView(accordionView: MKAccordionView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int, isSectionOpen sectionOpen: Bool) -> UIView? {

        var view : UIView! = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(accordionView.bounds), 50))

        // Background Image
        var bgImageView : UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: view.bounds)
        bgImageView.image = UIImage(named: ( sectionOpen ? "grayBarSelected" : "grayBar"))!
        view.addSubview(bgImageView)

        // Arrow Image
        var arrowImageView : UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(15, 15, 20, 20))
        arrowImageView.image = UIImage(named: ( sectionOpen ? "close" : "open"))!
        view.addSubview(arrowImageView)

        // Title Label
         titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(50, 0, CGRectGetWidth(view.bounds) - 120, CGRectGetHeight(view.bounds)))

        if (ChapName.count != 0) {
            let count = ChapName.count
            for index in 0...count-1 {
                titleLabel!.text = self.ChapName[index]
            }
        }
        titleLabel!.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        view.addSubview(titleLabel!)
        return view

        }
}
```

**Note:**

It shows me error because the ChapName & lesson name array are Empty. If i Hardcode the values. It prints both the array's in my console.

May be the accordionView doesn't support the reload Method?
or Where am I Going Wrong ?

**UPDATE**

1. numberOfSectionsInAccordionView throws Error like this `fatal error: Can't form Range with end < start` which on line 233
   Refer this [link](https://github.com/milankamilya/AccordianView/blob/master/AccordianView/View/MKAccordionView.swift#L233)

2.The titleLabel returns only the last item in the Array. I don't know Why ?

Comment: Blocking the UI thread is considered bad practice. Instead, you should show some sort of progress indicator before the data is available.

Comment: If any of the proposed answers work for you, you may want to tick *This answer was useful* in order to let others know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make sure all your json data is successfully stored into an array "accordionDataArray" before you attempt to reload it.

ATTENTION : make sure that the datasource methods **numberOfRowsInSection** and **numberOfSectionsInAccordionView** rely on the accordionDataArray content (or whatever Array you have) to determine the number of sections and rows of the accordion.

**P.S.** Anyway Why would you reload the content of the accordion in a loop?
Do this instead:

```
for index in 0...catCount-1 {
      let cname = json[index]["CHAPTER_NAME"].string
       self.ChapName.append(cname!)
       println(self.ChapName[index])
 }
 self.myAccordionView!.tableView?.reloadData()
```

**UPDATE:**
To get passed the fact that ChapName & lessonName array are asked for some value when they are Empty , you need to check that like this whenever they occur:

```
if (ChapName.count != 0) {
   titleLabel!.text = self.ChapName[0] 
}

if (LessonName.count != 0){
 // do something
}
```

Make sure you update your code and test. In the method:

```
func accordionView(accordionView: MKAccordionView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int, isSectionOpen sectionOpen: Bool) -> UIView? {

   [...]

   if (ChapName.count != 0) {
    titleLabel!.text = self.ChapName[0] 
   }

   [...]
}
```

**UPDATE 2:** The library you are using doesn't seem to allow the number of sections to be 0. I suggest you contact the library's owner if you can't make sure that the number of section is at least 1.

Regarding to your other issue with titleLabel being always the last item of the array you need to change this:

```
        if (ChapName.count != 0) {
        let count = ChapName.count
        for index in 0...count-1 {
            titleLabel!.text = self.ChapName[index]
        }
    }
```

into this:

```
titleLabel!.text = self.ChapName[section]
```

Comment: Can you print the whole error please. And at what point gets triggered? It shouldn't fire that error. Anyway just place checks whenever you try to access ChapName and lessonName array. If they are empty you simply don't ask for their content if (ChapName.count != 0) { titleLabel!.text = self.ChapName[0] } and the same for the lessonName array

Comment: I can access the Content with that method. But I can't get the Values at this method  numberOfSectionsInAccordionView

Comment: Can't i make the changes in the MKAccordionView.swift file

Comment: Please seek advice on these secondary issues. SO is not a blog ; it is aimed at recording accurate, specific answers to software development questions. Follow @uca's advice, build, run, test and vote.

Answer (score 0):

**About why the code above does not work:**
`numberOfRowsInSection` returns a hardcoded value, regardless of the JSON response.

**About stopping the UI thread:**
We are somewhat glad you can't do that. `GCD` helps you to share processor time efficiently, the exact opposite of holding the UI thread hostage. Image the consequence if somehow your network thread would hang. What would happen to the UI thread? Don't do it.

**Solutions**: Your make your UI thread clever enough to handle absence of datum. i.e. do not return hardcoded counts for sections or cells. When you receive data, update your records (the model), send a refresh message to the UI (such as `reloadData` in `UITableView`).

Comment: I hardcoded the Values for `numberOfRowsInSection` because the array is always empty. I have also tried the reloadData method in my code. Still it doesn't help me

Comment: The exception comes from the model `LessonName[indexPath.row]` to simply not have 15 entries. Make `numberOfRowsInSection` return `LessonName.count()`, not 15.